# wkhtmltopdf Import font rendering image instead of text

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I would like to use custom fonts with wkhtmltopdf and render my pdf with police integrated to it.

My customs fonts are "Biondy regular" and "Century Gothic". I bought them from "myfonts".

Throught a Symfony 3.4 application, I launch the generation of the PDF with somes parameters and CSS.

```
/**
 * Generate a PdfResponse.
 *
 * @param string $render
 * @param string $view
 * @param string $outputFileName
 * @param int $margin
 * @return PdfResponse
 */
public function generate(string $render, string $view, string $outputFileName, int $margin = 0): PdfResponse
{
    $options = [
        'user-style-sheet' => [
            'dir_to_my_css_file.css',
        ],
        'margin-top' => $margin,
        'margin-bottom' => $margin,
        'margin-left' => $margin,
        'margin-right' => $margin,
        'page-size' => 'A4',
    ];

    $pdf = $this->snappy->getOutputFromHtml($view, $options);

    return new PdfResponse($pdf, $outputFileName, 'application/pdf');
}
```

My PDF is well generated whith all the CSS and fonts. But it's an image not text.
If i remove my customs fonts, PDF is generated with text, not image.

To resolve the problem, I think I have to export my police to the PDF but I didn't found how to make that.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you provide more information, which custom fonts. where are you getting them from. Your question is not good enough to attract a good answer.

Comment: I edited my post. I hope it's enougth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve my problem, I installed fonts on my server.
It seems wkhtmltopdf use systems fonts for generation.
If fonts are not found, a pdf image is generated else it generate a pdf text.